# How can I filter a list inside a for?

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8

I recently had this problem.
This is my code

```
for(int i=1; i<=repeticiones;i++){
    posiblesComunes.removeIf(p->!periodos.get(i).contains(p));
}
```

periodos is a `List(Set(String))`, posiblesComunes is a `Set(String)`

What I need to do is get only the strings that are in all of the Set(String) in periodos.
I tried to do that using a for, but I get the next message:

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Is there any way to fix that? Or another way to get those elements?
Thanks!

edit:
Just an example

```
periodos = {("1-1-16","6-12-16"),("1-1-16","2-8-15"),("3-7-08","1-1-16")}
```

What I need to get is "1-1-16", the one in common.

edit2:

an example of periodosComunes (for the for loop):

```
periodosComunes = ("1-1-16","6-2-16")
```

Comment: instead of specifying the type of collections, it would be much more helpful to provide their definitions.

Comment: You can use a temp variable: `final int _i = i;`

Comment: Or you can probably just do `periodos.forEach(posiblesComunes::retainAll);`

Comment: @shmosel i dindn't see that option before for this problem. Could you explain a little more how retainAll works?

Comment: It keeps only elements in a given collection. Check the javadoc for more info.

Comment: i just edited the question, i think that retainAll doesn't work like that

Comment: You think based on what?? try it. @shmosel gave you a good solution.

Comment: Fair point. I just did it, trying to do the same thing in the example, and I just got an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (i'm using junit for testing)

Comment: Probably because `posiblesComunes` isn't modifiable.

Comment: I can't test it... Can anyone help?

Comment: post code example with definition and population of `periodos` and `posiblesComunes`

Comment: What is `periodosComunes`? Same as `possibleComunes`?

Comment: If `retainAll` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, then `removeIf` will do as well. It simply indicates that you have a collection that doesn’t support modifications. You can create a mutable copy using `periodosComunes = new HashSet<>(periodosComunes);`.

Answer (score 3):

You can not access the local variable `i` from a lambda expression, because it gets modified during the loop. The simplest fix is to capture the current value of `i` in another immutable variable:

```
for(int i=1; i<=repeticiones;i++) {
    int finalI = i;
    posiblesComunes.removeIf(p -> !periodos.get(finalI).contains(p));
}
```

Note that the variable of a for-each loop does not have this problem:

```
for(Set<String> set: periodos.subList(1, repeticiones))
    posiblesComunes.removeIf(p -> !set.contains(p));
```

but in the end, you are overusing Java 8 features here. This operation can be done with the original Collections API since Java 2:

```
for(Set<String> set: periodos.subList(1, repeticiones))
    posiblesComunes.retainAll(set);
```

which would also work with your original loop:

```
for(int i=1; i<=repeticiones; i++)
    posiblesComunes.retainAll(periodos.get(i));
```

Here, you could also add a short-cut, as the set never grows, so if there are no common elements, you can stop once the set became empty

```
for(int i=1; i<=repeticiones && !posiblesComunes.isEmpty(); i++)
    posiblesComunes.retainAll(periodos.get(i));
```

Comment: Nice explaination. You always give us surprise from a common question.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Set<String> periodosComunes = Set.of("1-1-16","6-2-16");
List<Set<String>> periodos = List.of(
  Set.of("1-1-16","6-12-16"),
  Set.of("1-1-16","2-8-15"),
  Set.of("3-7-08","1-1-16")
);

List<String> result = periodosComunes.stream()
  .filter(x -> periodos.stream()
      .allMatch(y -> y.contains(x))
  )
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

// result = [1-1-16]
```

I used collection literals from Java 9 to save me some typing, but that's irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: The `distinct()` call is obsolete when you are collecting into a `Set`. But anyway, your `whitelist` contains the union of all sets, instead of the intersection, so `whitelist::contains` will accept an element as soon as it is in *any* of the sets rather than *all* of the sets.

Comment: @Holger I'd missed that requirement; updated my answer accordingly. It actually makes things simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I make a mess using a for loop D:

Answer (score 1):

Not all lists provide iterators with the ability to remove their items; however, if you select the right kind of list, this is built into the `Iterator` interface.

```
Iterator i = list.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (i.next().equals(bad)) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

The simplicity of the solution is enough you might consider skipping the Stream based approach, and unlike some kinds of modifications, `Iterator` removal will not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: It's "simple" because you conveniently omitted where `bad` comes from. Stream or no stream, as soon as you flatten the other list, you end up with what I've suggested. Not to mention immutability etc.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Bad is the object containing the values you are filtering out.  Actually, you can put anything into the conditional, and the `i.remove()` will work.  If one cannot figure out how to determine what they want removed, then that's a much larger problem, which can't be solved with code.

Comment: I understand what `bad` is in your code. I'm questioning the claim that using `Iterator` is anyway simpler or better than using `Stream`, mostly because it's 2017.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The simple solution you provided is six lines of code, where one has a Producer, a flatMap, and a Collector, as a minimum above the starting List.  Mine has an Iterator.  That's one Class vs 3, and you don't even need to be fully up-to-date on your Streaming semantics.  If that's not simpler, then what is?  It is 2017, and now we need Training, Testing, and Insurance before one can get their Driver's License.  My Grandma got hers with a signature, and had never driven a car.  Newer is not always simpler :) .

Comment: You're missing quite a few points. 1. Your code is not compilable. If and when you make it compile, we will see how many lines you save 2. Fewer lines doesn't equate to simplicity; I can keep appending statements with `;` in one line, claiming that it makes the code simpler, but it'd be stupid. 3. If you sleep better believing you've provided a better solution, that's fine with me; I'm not here competing with you for a job interview.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Chill out.  There's more than one way to write a solution, and you're all upset because I presented an Iterator?  You're right that it's a good thing we aren't competing in an interview, I wouldn't hire a person who was going to work with my teams the way you're working with me.

Comment: I'm not upset, I just don't like people who are closed minded. I'll get my coat.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Close minded?  I'm happy for you to have your answer, but you're not happy with mine.  If you can't concede that there are such things as Iterators, I'm not the close minded one.  "Rarely a pain in the ass?"  I suggest you read your bio and then try to live by it.

Comment: If the task’s condition was as simple as `if (i.next().equals(bad))`, I’d use `list.remove(bad)` instead of dealing with an `Iterator` manually. Ironically, the OP’s task, while being different, has such a simple existing Collection operation too…

Comment: @Holger list.remove(bad) is a good pattern, but it often reindexes the list in such a way that an index based walk needs to be careful.  Also, if using the list in a foreach style loop, it tends to trip the concurrent modification logic.  If the iterator supports remove, using the iterator tends to not break the walk of the list, for the single iterator in question. Any way, there are a lot of approaches to this one, and I can see a list.remove(...) working just as nicely.

Comment: My suggestion wasn’t to combine `list.remove` with an index based walk, but not to use a manual walk at all, *if* the operation can be expressed as a plain Collection operation. Here, it isn’t `remove` but `retainAll` which solves the OP’s task…

Comment: @Holger Sounds like a pretty good solution.  If you write it up as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Edwin Buck: [I already did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45545464/2711488), see the second half of the answer…

Comment: @Holger And you got my upvote.  Nice chatting with you.

Answer (score 0):

That should work (if I understand well your needs):

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;
public class P {

  public static void main(String []a) {
    // Init.
    Set<String> periodosComunes = new HashSet<>(); periodosComunes.add("1-1-16"); periodosComunes.add("6-2-16");
    Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>(); s1.add("1-1-16"); s1.add("6-12-16");
    Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>(); s2.add("1-1-16"); s2.add("2-8-15");
    Set<String> s3 = new HashSet<>(); s3.add("1-1-16"); s3.add("3-7-08");
    List<Set<String>> periodos = new ArrayList<>(); periodos.add(s1); periodos.add(s2); periodos.add(s3);

    // Computes the set of commons...
    Set<String> r =  periodosComunes.stream().filter(p->periodos.stream().allMatch(s->s.contains(p))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(r);                                                   
  }
}
```

The set of common periods initially in `periodosCommunes` is in `r`. Now you can use that set to remove appropriate ones in the original set if needed:

```
periodosComunes.removeIf(s->!r.contains(s));
```